# XML Jquery Local Folder

Tags: jquery, xml

I´m trying to display the images locally first to test, then upload the html to a server, with the current code is not showing any data on Chrome, in FF and IE it´s showing great but my problem is, the script is not showing the imagemNode that are inside the "imagens" folder, it only display the  location. I´ve tried to create a var for the location but still doesnt work. This is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $.get('topico765.xml', function(d)
        {
            $('body').append('<h1>XML com jQuery<img src="imagens/13451.jpg"/></h1>');
            $('body').append('<dl/>');

            $(d).find('tela').each(function()
            {
                var $slide = $(this); 
                <!--var topicoNode = $slide.attr("nome");
                var textoNode = $slide.children("texto").text();
                <!--var location = "imagens/";
                var imagemNode = $slide.children("imagem")
                var html = '<dt><img class="imagem" alt="'+$(imagemNode).text()+'" src="imagens/"'+imagemNode+'"/></dt>';
                html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Carregando" />';
                html += '<p>Posicao Intervencao Y: '+intervencaoY+'</p>';
                html += '<p>'+textoNode+'</p>';
                html += '</dd>';
                $('dl').append($(html));
                $('.loadingPic').slideUp(2000);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My XML is a third party company that send us so we can´t change anything, otherwise I just place the path "imagens" in the beginning of the tag .

Answer (score 0):

Small error fixed:

```
var html = '<dt><img class="imagem" alt="" src="'+location+''+(imagemNode)+'"/></dt>';
```